snowflake staging file size
Is there a way to get only parquet file size of snowflake staging.
LIST command is showing the following columns -  name, size, md5 and last_modified



name
size
md5
last_modified




s3://sample_bucket/zone/table1/sys_cd=local/part-00000-abcld.00000.snappy.parquet
303200
fab1234cbxyandfdskanf
Mon, Dec 2024 04:07:36 GMT



Is there a way to return only size, please share your inputs.

you can try using result_scan of the last query.
list @stage_file_name pattern = '\.*parquet';
select $1 as file_name, $2 as size from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) ;


This is not giving size from LIST output

can you please send us the output of the list@stage_file_name.

name size md5  last_modified
s3://sample_bucket/zone/table1/sys_cd=local/part-00000-abcld.00000.snappy.parquet 303200 fab1234cbxyandfdskanf Mon, Dec 2024 04:07:36 GMT

Isn’t 303200 the size? If you pasted the output into your question and formatted it as a table, it would be easier to read

yes 303200 is the size

Then I’m not sure why you wrote a comment “ This is not giving size from LIST output” when you’ve just shown that it is?

I want to print only size

Which is exactly what @HimanshuKandpal's answer does. Can you explain why that answer doesn't achieve what you want?
